# Failed due ftp PORT command

Tags: c++, sockets, ftp, ipv6

I am trying to implement IPv6/IPv4 dual stack FTP connection. I succesfully implemented almost all  parts of functionality, but I got stacked on PORT command. When I am trying to send it I got :

```
421 Service not available, closing control connection. Timeout expired.
```

This is kind a stange, cause I know that on IPv6 you do not actually need port command, and first four numbers are ignored. I am sending PORT command in this format:

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,p1,p2
```

Thanks on advance.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong assumption: a port-like command is necessary and has a different syntax. The new commands are `ERPT` and `EPSV`. Some examples:

```
EPRT |2|1080::8:800:200C:417A|5282|
EPSV 2
```

Look at [RFC 2428](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2428) for the full specifications.

Comment: do you mean that these commands should be used in case of IPv6 ?